# Websphere error SRVE0133E: and reason RC: 107

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere

I am getting this error on WebSphere Server Log(s)

SRVE0133E: An error occurred while parsing parameters. java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed, reason: RC: 107  Transport endpoint is not connected

can anyone help me and guide me about the reason of this error?

Thanks :)

**EDIT**

```
SRVE0133E: An error occurred while parsing parameters. java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed, reason: RC: 107  Transport endpoint is not connected
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:679)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)
```

Comment: Which version of WebSphere? Did you web-search for the error code (SRVE0133E)?

Comment: I am getting the same error when I upload a big file. Did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can occur if the client (e.g. a browser) requests content from the server,
then closes the connection before the server sends the response.

Answer (score 2):

There are some tech notes which relates to this.

http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM10292

Does that apply to your case?

You also have to place in a few more lines from the stack for people to see what is likely happening under the hood.

HTH